# How to export and import class methods in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

i have this simply class like below:

```
export class Test {
    constructor(
        private readolny somStuff: SomeStuff;
    ) {}

    async simpleMethod(): Promise<any> {
        return { test: "test" }
    }
}
```

how can i import only `simpleMethod` in another .ts file with using this import statement?

```
import { simpleMethod } from '../../test.ts';
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't, because it's not exported; only the class is exported. But why would you want to import a (non-static) method separately? You cannot call it without a class instance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing this but you can either export the type definition or the method itself by using the prototype.

```js
export type simpleMethodType = typeof Test['prototype']["simpleMethod"];
export const simpleMethod = Test.prototype.simpleMethod.bind(null);
```

The `bind` method makes sure that you can use the method without wrong context.
If your wanted method is `static`, you don't have to use the prototype.